# Create a vector with vertices at a fixed distance in order to add transects

Tags: geometry, geoprocessing

I am trying to create transects along the shape of the coastline.
I need that these transects are regularly spaced (e.g. 110 meters afar from each other at the starting point on the shape).
I have been suggested that the tool transect creates transects starting on vertices and one possibility is to use the tool densify.

If possible, how to do in order that the vector of the coastline has regularly spaced vertices so that the corresponding transects are placed at a fixed distance?

Comment: What software are you using? You should add it as a tag and maybe put it in the title and text too.

Answer (score 1):

If your initial line has vertices with a larger interval then the distance you want (like e.g. every 110 m). run `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Densify by interval` and set the interval to 110. You will get a line with additional vertices every 110 meters.

---

The initial vertices will be kept. If you want a solution without the initial vertices, just a transect every 110 meters, proceed like this:

1. Run `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Points along geometry` with the distance you want.
2. Run `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Points to path` to create a new, simplified line with just the vertices every 110 m.

Comment: Thanks. I have found also this tool: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/48663